# Does it an error that professional javascript for web developers tell us how object convert to number?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

Look at below code, what should it output ?

```js
let obj = Object.create(null);
obj.valueOf = function () { console.log('hit valueOf!'); return "TO BE NaN";};
obj.toString = function () { console.log('hit toString!'); return "1";};
Number(obj)

// ?
```

According to professinal javascript, valueOf function returns "TO BE NaN" , and it will be convert to NaN, then toString function called.

- Number Conversions

> When applied to objects, the valueOf() method is called and the returned value is converted
> based on the previously described rules. If that conversion results in NaN, the toString()
> method is called and the rules for converting strings are applied.

As a matter of fact, it shows things here, function toString not called !

```js
let obj = Object.create(null);
obj.valueOf = function () { console.log('hit valueOf!'); return "TO BE NaN";};
obj.toString = function () { console.log('hit toString!'); return "1";};
Number(obj)

// hit valueOf!
// NaN
```

Does it an error that professional javascript for web developers tell us how object convert to number?

Comment: I have no idea what this “professional javascript for web developers” is or what “error” you’re talking about, but have you tried reading the [docs for `Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) or [`valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf), or the [spec for `Number`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-number-constructor-number-value) or [`OrdinaryToPrimitive`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinarytoprimitive) (which is the relevant behavior of picking `valueOf` or `toString`)?

Comment: Apparently “Professional JavaScript for Web Developers” is a book and you’re asking if it contains a mistake. Maybe; I don’t know the full context of that quote. Of the two methods `toString` and `valueOf` only one is called. There is no such behavior that one method serves as a “fallback” of the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's a mistake in your book (and [not the only one](https://github.com/msfrisbie/professional-javascript-for-web-developers/blob/master/errata.md)).

It should read more like<sup>1</sup>

> When applied to objects, the `valueOf()` method is called and the returned value is converted based on the previously described rules *if it is a primitive value*. If *<s>that conversion results in NaN</s> it returns an object*, the `toString()` method is called and the rules for converting strings are applied.

Demonstrated:

```js
const obj = Object.create(null);
obj.valueOf = function () { console.log('hit valueOf!'); return {};};
obj.toString = function () { console.log('hit toString!'); return "1";};
console.log(Number(obj))
```

<sub>1: Although still not quite correct. It should mention that the two methods are called only if they exist, and that an error is thrown if they both return an object.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

`Number(value)`, according to the specification, [calls](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-number-constructor-number-value) `ToNumeric(value)`, which returns `ToPrimitive(value, number)`. This second argument is the `preferredType`, [resulting in](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinarytoprimitive):

> If hint is string, then

> Let methodNames be « "toString", "valueOf" ».

> Else,

> Let methodNames be « "valueOf", "toString" ».

> For each element name of methodNames, do

> a. Let method be ? Get(O, name).

> b. If IsCallable(method) is true, then

> 1. Let result be ? Call(method, O).

> 2. If Type(result) is not Object, return result.

So in the case of `Number(obj)`, the `valueOf` method really is supposed to be invoked first.

In other words, whatever the following sentence came from is incorrect:

> When applied to objects, the valueOf() method is called and the returned value is converted based on the previously described rules. If that conversion results in NaN, the toString() method is called and the rules for converting strings are applied.